# How do I split a string ONLY after the first instance of the comma?

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
LicPlate = ""
FData = DtReader.ReadLine() & vbCrLf
FData = FData.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
RequestedBy = Split(FData, ",", 2)
LicPlate = (RequestedBy(0))
Description1 = (RequestedBy(1))
```

So, LicPlate = Test and Description1 = "testing, yes"
I want to make it so that Description1 = testing, yes, how to show this result?

How do I split the RequestedBy string at the first instance of a Comma ","?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Okay, but solve this problem. please help me.

Comment: Can you show us an example of `FData`?

Comment: FData=GHGSA,"testing, yes'" but i have need output FData=GHGSA,testing, yes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `IndexOf` to find the first appearance of `,` and then using `Substring` worked for me:

```
Dim str = "x,y,z"
Dim i = str.IndexOf(",")
Dim part1 = str.Substring(0, i)
Dim part2 = str.Substring(i + 1)
```

Then `part1` is `x` and `part2` is `y,z`.

Comment: Description1 = FData.Substring(RequestedBy + 1, FData.Length - RequestedBy - 1)   this is error operator '-' is not defined for types 'object' and 'string()' and operator '+' is not defined for types 'object' and 'string()'

Comment: Well, I cannot debug your code. To confirm my solution, you can copy the code and paste it and run it to see the result. Then apply it on your existing methods.

Comment: if you don't specify the length, it takes the rest of the string. So you could just use `Dim part2 = str.Substring(i+1)` to get `y,z`.

Comment: @CharlesMay Cool! It's better now.

Answer (score -1):

i am add only bottom line code that's solve my problem 
the code is

```
        Dim Description = Description1.Replace("""", "").Trim()
```

above line is add after run

```
        LicPlate = ""
        FData = DtReader.ReadLine() & vbCrLf
        FData = FData.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
        RequestedBy = Split(FData, ",", 2)
        LicPlate = (RequestedBy(0))
        Description1 = (RequestedBy(1))
        Dim Description = Description1.Replace("""", "").Trim()
```

Comment: You said ["thanks your help , my problem is solved now"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087074/how-do-i-split-a-string-only-after-the-first-instance-of-the-comma/51088280#comment89167353_51088280)! Why do you need to add your own answer while you have a good answer for your question?